# Using array entries as indexs to access another array

Tags: assembly, masm

I want to be able to use array entries as indexes for accessing a second array.

```
; array declarations:

f_index BYTE SIZEOF array1 DUP(?) ; has 10 entries 0,3,5,...
array2 BYTE 31,45,65,71,43,44,67,50,32,52,20,29,30,40,45,50,56,60,75,25

mov edx,OFFSET f_index   ; pointer to f_index array

mov ebx,[edx]            ; ebx = 0

mov esi,array2[ebx]      ; esi = 31

cmp esi,55               ; compare 31 and 55
```

However, my error is at mov esi,array2[ebx] I am using MASM Assembly for x86 Intel processors. 
The error says invalid instruction operands.

Comment: Well, you're using the wrong instructions. To load a byte from memory into a 32-bit register you should use either `movzx` or `movsx` (e.g. `movzx ebx,byte ptr [edx]`). But `mov ebx,[edx]` should still be a legal instruction, so it surprises me that you get an error on that line.

Comment: Sorry wrong line! The error is while accessing array2 with index 0 and moving that into esi register. I did fix the other one at your suggestion.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with that line either (other than that it also should be a `movzx`/`movsx`). I'd write the address as `[array2 + ebx]`, but I think MASM accepts both ways of writing it.

Comment: Your `f_index` array that has the offset values listed is wrong. BYTE is 2 bits, so it should be 0,2,4,...

But it shouldn't cause a problem moving to esi. This would just display the wrong information.